# JSON not loading to pandas, JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

So I have a set of JSON objects, that I need to transform into CSVs.

the data looks like this, same across all files:

```json
{"data":
   [{ "id": "1234",
      "names": [
          "john",
          "bill",
          "ted"
          ],
      "active": {
          "john": "no",
          "bill": "yes",
          "ted" : "yes"
          }
    }]
}
```

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(r'path\to\json.json', orient="split")
df.to_csv(r'path\to\folder.csv')
```

It worked for the first one. When I tried to run it on the other folders in the file, it gave me a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value`, but they are all literally exactly the same.

Comment: Assuming that df = pd.read_json(r'path\to\json.json', orient="split") is you simply changing the path. Your json file could be empty.

Comment: They are not. They all have thousands of lines of data, and are syntactically correct JSON files. And there are no leading white spaces before the object "begins"

Comment: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value. This error means the decoder fail to receive any value from whatever it's getting the data from, so either the file is empty, Or you used the wrong Orient value.

Comment: Yes, I know what it means, but I have several identical JSON files and it doesn't make sense that it would function on one of them and not the others?

Comment: Now I'm getting an `expected object or value` error, so I don't know if that's moving backwards or forwards.

Comment: I think we need you to provide a reproducible example to solve this. As you mentioned the code you posted here works so any answers are just guesses.

Comment: @B.Bogart this is literally all the code I have, other than the actual data, which I'm not permitted to share.

Comment: That code doesn't loop or import any files other than the one.